# Link rows from two QTableView for visual comparaison

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qtableview

I am trying to develop a GUI to managed scientific results. For this, I would like to present result from two datasets. The user would have a visual reprentation to help him to compare those results in two QTableView.

Image : comparer Result,

[image]

I want to link lines from the two table, so they always be present face to face.
When order change in one table, the other will follow and adapt its order to still have the linked lines face to face.
Eventually i would like to add empty row face to a line that haven't a relative line in the other table.

I was think to use a QSortFilterProxyModel but I am not sure how to use it.

**Edit**
My Question seem to be not clear. I Formulate here. I find myself a solution so here a example of what I was looking.

[image: small Comparaison]
On this example line I link line according to the name (bla, bli blo, blu). We see on the same line, tables present face to face line of result "bla" and "bli", because there are in both left model and right.
There is no "blu" in the right table. so i add a empty line. 
Idem in the left table with "blo"

In this example item are sorted with "configuration" of the right table. Left table have to follow the order choose by the right table.

Here my code without the solution

```
class Result(object):
    def __init__(self, headerOrder, infoResult):
        for n, headerName in enumerate(headerOrder):
            self.__setattr__(headerName, infoResult[n])

        self.diff = self.reference_redshift - self.estimate
```

ModelClass

```
class Result_model(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):

    def __init__(self,  header, parent=None):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.__datas = []
        self.__headers = header

    def rowCount(self, parent=None):
        return len(self.__datas)

    def columnCount(self, parent=None):
        return len(self.__headers)

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.ToolTipRole:
            row = index.row()
            column = index.column()
            return "{}: {}".format(self.__headers[column], getattr(self.__datas[row], self.__headers[column]))

        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:

            row = index.row()
            column = index.column()
            value = getattr(self.__datas[row], self.__headers[column])

            return value

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):

        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:

            if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:

                if section < len(self.__headers):
                    return self.__headers[section]
                else:
                    return "not implemented"
            else:
                return section

    def supportedDragActions(self):
        return QtCore.Qt.CopyAction

    def supportedDropActions(self):
        return Qt.CopyAction | Qt.MoveAction

    def getResult(self, index):
        row = index.row()
        return self.__datas[row]

    def sort(self, Ncol, order):
        """Sort table by given column number.
        """
        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("layoutAboutToBeChanged()"))
        attribut = self.__headers[Ncol]
        self.__datas = sorted(
            self.__datas, key=lambda x: getattr(x, attribut), reverse=(order == QtCore.Qt.DescendingOrder))

        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("layoutChanged()"))

    def addResults(self, results):
        self.beginInsertRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), len(
            self.__datas), len(self.__datas) + len(results))
        for res in results:
            self.__datas.append(res)
        self.endInsertRows()
```

TableView only Drag

```
class TableResult(QtGui.QTableView):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QTableView.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.setDragDropMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)
        self.header, self.aid_index = [["aid", "estimate", "reference_redshift", "diff", "amazed_executable_id", "amazed_configuration_id",
                                        "astronomical_object_name", "star_forming_rate", "magnitude", "log_f_halpha", "emission_velocity_dispersion", "res_dir"], 0]
        self.tag_info_result = ["aid", "estimate", "reference_redshift",  "amazed_executable_id", "amazed_configuration_id",
                                "astronomical_object_name", "star_forming_rate", "magnitude", "log_f_halpha", "emission_velocity_dispersion", "res_dir"]
        self.setItemDelegateForColumn(self.aid_index, ButtonDelegate(self))
        self.parent = parent

    def startDrag(self, dropAction):
        if(self.parent is not None and hasattr(self.parent, "selection")):
            # create mime data object
            mime = QtCore.QMimeData()
            # start drag
            drag = QtGui.QDrag(self)
            drag.setMimeData(mime)
            drag.start(QtCore.Qt.CopyAction | QtCore.Qt.CopyAction)
        else:
            print("Drag impossible")

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.startDrag(event)
```

TableView with drop

```
class Selection_receiver(TableResult):
    "Add the drop possibility from TableResult"

    def __init__(self, setResultFunction, parent=None):
        TableResult.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setResultFunction = setResultFunction

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if (isinstance(event.source(), TableResult)):
            event.accept()
            event.acceptProposedAction()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        print("dropEvent")
        if (isinstance(event.source(), TableResult)):
            event.acceptProposedAction()
            model_result = event.source().parent.resModel
            self.setResultFunction(model_result)
        else:
            event.ignore()
```

The Widget presenting the two Tables

```
class Comparater_result_widget(QtGui.QWidget):
    """
    Present two table for easy comparaison.
    """

    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Result Comparer")
        main_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()

        receiverSplitter = QtGui.QSplitter()
        receiverSplitter.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.left_receiver = Selection_receiver(self.setLeftResult)
        receiverSplitter.addWidget(self.left_receiver)

        self.right_receiver = Selection_receiver( self.setRightResult)
        receiverSplitter.addWidget(self.right_receiver)

        main_layout.addWidget(receiverSplitter)

        self.left_receiver.horizontalScrollBar().valueChanged.connect(
            self.right_receiver.horizontalScrollBar().setValue)
        self.right_receiver.horizontalScrollBar().valueChanged.connect(
            self.left_receiver.horizontalScrollBar().setValue)
        self.left_receiver.verticalScrollBar().valueChanged.connect(
            self.right_receiver.verticalScrollBar().setValue)
        self.right_receiver.verticalScrollBar().valueChanged.connect(
            self.left_receiver.verticalScrollBar().setValue)

        self.right_results = None
        self.left_results = None
        self.setLayout(main_layout)

    def setLeftResult(self, model_result):
        print("setLeftResult []".format(model_result))
        self.left_results = model_result
        self.add_model_result(self.left_receiver, model_result)

    def setRightResult(self, model_result):
        print("setRightResult {}".format(model_result))
        self.right_results = model_result
        self.add_model_result(self.right_receiver, model_result)

    def add_model_result(self, receiver, model_result):
        receiver.setModel(model_result)

        if(self.right_results is not None and self.left_results is not None):
            self.link_result()

    def link_result(self):
        # parse the two model and link results if the have equal on one
        # particular attribut
        pass

    def OnLeftChangeOrder(self):
        # somthing like right_proxy.reorder(left_order)
        pass

    def OnRightChangeOrder(self):
        # something link left_proxy.reorder(right_order)
        pass
```

Comment: Your description is confusing, you could explain me better please.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution i created.

I use Two Proxy:

- my own mapping proxy model ("MixRowProxyModel")
- a almost normal QSortFilterProxyModel ("MySortProxyModel")

Source model is the model of MixRowProxyModel.
MixRowProxyModel is the model of MySortProxyModel

Table can be in two state, master or slave. If I sort the right table at one column, the right become master and the left is slave.

When a table is master, its MySortProxyModel is active, MixRowProxyModel is inactive

When a table is slave, its MySortProxyModel is inactive, MixRowProxyModel is active

When the two source model are set. I create a map between rows of the sources models. This map will not change when table are sorted.

When a table become slave i construct the mapping for its MixRowProxyModel (see method change in Comparater_result_widget). For that i use the initial mapping i created between modelsource.

```
class MixRowProxyModel(QtGui.QAbstractProxyModel):

    def __init__(self, controller, side, parent=None):
        QtGui.QAbstractProxyModel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.nbEmpty = 0
        self.mapProxyToSource = None
        self.isMaster = True
        self.side = side

    def setMap(self, mapping):
        self.isMaster = False
        self.mapProxyToSource = mapping
        self.mapSourceToProxy = {v: k for k,
                                 v in self.mapProxyToSource.items()}

    def mapFromSource(self, sourceIndex):
        #print("MixRowProxyModel Proxy Index model {}".format(sourceIndex.model()))
        if(not sourceIndex.isValid()):
            return self.index(-1, -1)
        if(self.isMaster):
            return self.index(sourceIndex.row(), sourceIndex.column(), parent=QtCore.QModelIndex)
        else:
            row = sourceIndex.row()
            if(row in self.mapSourceToProxy):
                return self.index(self.mapSourceToProxy[row], sourceIndex.column())
            else:
                print("Invalid sourceIndex {}".format(row))
                return self.index(-1, -1)

    def mapToSource(self, proxyIndex):
        if(not proxyIndex.isValid()):
            return self.sourceModel().index(-1, -1)
        if(self.isMaster):
            return self.sourceModel().index(proxyIndex.row(), proxyIndex.column())
        else:
            row = proxyIndex.row()
            if(row in self.mapProxyToSource):
                return self.sourceModel().index(self.mapProxyToSource[row], proxyIndex.column())
            else:
                # print("Invalid proxyIndex {}".format(row))
                return self.sourceModel().index(-1, -1)

    def rowCount(self, parent=None):

        return self.sourceModel().rowCount() + self.nbEmpty

    def columnCount(self, parent=None):

        return self.sourceModel().columnCount()

    def addEmptyRow(self):
        print("addEmptyRow {}".format(self.side))
        self.beginInsertRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(),
                             self.rowCount(),  self.rowCount())

        self.nbEmpty += 1
        self.endInsertRows()
        return -1

    def parent(self, index):
        return QtCore.QModelIndex()

    def index(self, row, column, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex):
        if(row >= self.rowCount() or row < 0 or column < 0 or column >= self.columnCount()):
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

        return self.createIndex(row, column, parent)

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):

        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:

            if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:

                return self.sourceModel().headerData(section, orientation, role)
            else:
                return section

    def flags(self, index):
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):

        if(not index.isValid()):
            return None
        if(self.isMaster):
            if(index.row() < self.sourceModel().rowCount()):
                return self.sourceModel().data(index, role)
            else:
                return None
        else:
            if(not index.row() in self.mapProxyToSource):
                return None
            return self.sourceModel().data(self.sourceModel().index(self.mapProxyToSource[index.row()], index.column()), role)
```

the second ProxyModel

```
class MySortProxyModel(QtGui.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    sortedSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtCore.Qt.SortOrder)

    def sort(self, column, order):
        self.sourceModel().isMaster = True
        #print("Sort order : {} sort Role {}".format(order, self.sortRole()))
        self.setSortRole(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
        super().sort(column, order)

        self.sortedSignal.emit(order)

the Parent Widget controlling the two tables

class Comparater_result_widget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, controller, parent=None):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__(parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.setWindowTitle("Result Comparer")
        main_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()

        receiverSplitter = QtGui.QSplitter()
        receiverSplitter.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.left_receiver = Selection_receiver(
            self.controller, self.setLeftResult)
        receiverSplitter.addWidget(self.left_receiver)

        self.right_receiver = Selection_receiver(
            self.controller, self.setRightResult)
        receiverSplitter.addWidget(self.right_receiver)

        main_layout.addWidget(receiverSplitter)

        self.left_receiver.horizontalScrollBar().valueChanged.connect(
            self.right_receiver.horizontalScrollBar().setValue)
        self.right_receiver.horizontalScrollBar().valueChanged.connect(
            self.left_receiver.horizontalScrollBar().setValue)
        self.left_receiver.verticalScrollBar().valueChanged.connect(
            self.right_receiver.verticalScrollBar().setValue)
        self.right_receiver.verticalScrollBar().valueChanged.connect(
            self.left_receiver.verticalScrollBar().setValue)

        self.right_source_model = None
        self.right_proxy_model = None
        self.right_proxy_model2 = None
        self.left_source_model = None
        self.left_proxy_model = None
        self.left_proxy_model2 = None

        self.setLayout(main_layout)

    def setLeftResult(self, model_result):
        self.left_source_model = model_result
        self.left_proxy_model = MixRowProxyModel(
            self.controller, "left", parent=self)
        # self.left_proxy_model.sortedSignal.connect(self.onLeftChange)
        self.left_proxy_model.setSourceModel(self.left_source_model)
        self.left_proxy_model2 = MySortProxyModel(parent=self)
        self.left_proxy_model2.sortedSignal.connect(self.onLeftChange)
        self.left_proxy_model2.setSourceModel(self.left_proxy_model)
        self.add_model_result(self.left_receiver, self.left_proxy_model2)

    def setRightResult(self, model_result):
        self.right_source_model = model_result
        self.right_proxy_model = MixRowProxyModel(
            self.controller, "right", parent=self)
        self.right_proxy_model.setSourceModel(self.right_source_model)
        # self.right_proxy_model.sortedSignal.connect(self.onRightChange)

        self.right_proxy_model2 = MySortProxyModel(parent=self)
        self.right_proxy_model2.sortedSignal.connect(self.onRightChange)
        self.right_proxy_model2.setSourceModel(self.right_proxy_model)
        self.add_model_result(self.right_receiver, self.right_proxy_model2)

    def add_model_result(self, receiver, model_result):
        receiver.setModel(model_result)

        if(self.right_source_model is not None and self.left_source_model is not None):
            self.link_result()

    def link_result(self):
        name_to_row = {}
        for numSourceLeftRow in range(self.left_source_model.rowCount()):
            res = self.left_source_model.getResultNumRow(numSourceLeftRow)
            name = res.astronomical_object_name
            if(name in name_to_row):
                name_to_row[name][0].append(numSourceLeftRow)
            else:
                name_to_row[name] = ([numSourceLeftRow], [])

        for numSourceRightRow in range(self.right_source_model.rowCount()):
            res = self.right_source_model.getResultNumRow(numSourceRightRow)
            name = res.astronomical_object_name
            if(name in name_to_row):
                name_to_row[name][1].append(numSourceRightRow)
            else:
                name_to_row[name] = ([], [numSourceRightRow])
        self.mapLeftToRight = {}  # key = leftRow; value = rightRow
        self.mapRightToLeft = {}  # key = rightRow; value = leftRow
        for list_leftRow, list_rightRow in name_to_row.values():
            if(len(list_rightRow) > 1):
                print(
                    "Error more that index at right for same astronomical name {}".list_rightRow)
            if(len(list_leftRow) > 1):
                print(
                    "Error more that index at left for same astronomical name {}".list_leftRow)
            if(len(list_leftRow) == 0):
                leftRow = self.left_proxy_model.addEmptyRow()
            else:
                leftRow = list_leftRow[0]
            if(len(list_rightRow) == 0):
                rightRow = self.right_proxy_model.addEmptyRow()
            else:
                rightRow = list_rightRow[0]

            self.mapLeftToRight[leftRow] = rightRow
            self.mapRightToLeft[rightRow] = leftRow
        self.left_receiver.rowCountChanged(
            self.left_source_model.rowCount(), self.left_proxy_model.rowCount())
        self.right_receiver.rowCountChanged(
            self.right_source_model.rowCount(), self.right_proxy_model.rowCount())
        print("Link Done : LtoR : {}; RtoL {}".format(
            self.mapLeftToRight, self.mapRightToLeft))

    def onRightChange(self, order):
        print("RightChange")
        self.change(self.left_source_model, self.left_proxy_model, self.left_proxy_model2, self.right_source_model, self.right_proxy_model,
                    self.right_proxy_model2, self.mapLeftToRight, self.left_receiver, order)

    def onLeftChange(self, order):
        print("LeftChange")
        self.change(self.right_source_model, self.right_proxy_model, self.right_proxy_model2, self.left_source_model, self.left_proxy_model,
                    self.left_proxy_model2, self.mapRightToLeft, self.right_receiver, order)

    def change(self, slave_source_model, slave_proxy_model,
               slave_proxy_model2, master_source_model, master_proxy_model, master_proxy_model2,
               map_slave_to_master, slave_receiver, order):
        if(slave_source_model is not None):

            slaveMapping = dict()  # in slave table key = indexProxy , value = index Source
            if(order == QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder):
                unlinkIndex = 0
            else:
                unlinkIndex = master_source_model.rowCount()
            for slaveSourceRow in range(slave_source_model.rowCount()):

                # this line is link to one in master, so we keep the same
                # proxy number
                master_source_row = map_slave_to_master[slaveSourceRow]
                if(master_source_row != -1):
                    master_source_index = master_source_model.index(
                        master_source_row, 0)
                    master_proxy = master_proxy_model.mapFromSource(
                        master_source_index)
                    master_proxy2 = master_proxy_model2.mapFromSource(
                        master_proxy)
                    slaveProxyRow = master_proxy2.row()  # same as master
                else:
                    slaveProxyRow = unlinkIndex  # we put it at the end or begining depending on order
                    unlinkIndex += 1

                slaveMapping[slaveProxyRow] = slaveSourceRow

            slave_proxy_model.layoutAboutToBeChanged.emit()
            slave_proxy_model.setMap(slaveMapping)
            slave_proxy_model2.setSortRole(
                QtCore.Qt.InitialSortOrderRole)  # proxy 2 is reinitialise
            slave_proxy_model.layoutChanged.emit()
```